# How to make a mysqli statement between two tables

Tags: mysqli

I have two tables in one MySQLI database. One is called 'actions' and one is called 'links'. But recently I have noticed that many links which I have transfered from my old system don't have any actions attached to it, and I want to count how many they are. So I want to count the amount of links whose id hasn't any entries in the actions table. How can I formulate the statement. There is one id in the links table and one link_id in the actions table.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a outer join. without a lot of details, it would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM links
  LEFT JOIN actions on links.field = actions.field
  WHERE actions.ID is NULL;
```

This will give you all the links records that don't have a corresponding record in actions.